# Magento 1.9.2.3 - Wishlist issue

Tags: magento

would like to ask you some help regarding an issue I'm having in the wishlist section. When we add a product as favourite, this message appears as an error.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setItems() on boolean in /home2/***/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/sinprecio/template/wishlist/view.phtml on line 43
```

This is the code in the view.phtml

```html
<?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
<div class="my-wishlist">
    <div class="page-title title-buttons">
        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isRssAllow() && $this->hasWishlistItems()): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getRssUrl($this->getWishlistInstance()->getId()); ?>" class="link-rss"><?php echo $this->__('RSS Feed') ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <h1><?php echo $this->getTitle(); ?></h1>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>

    <form id="wishlist-view-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/update', array('wishlist_id' => $this->getWishlistInstance()->getId())) ?>" method="post">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('top'); ?>
        <fieldset>
            <?php if ($this->hasWishlistItems()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey');?>
                    <?php $this->getChild('items')->setItems($this->getWishlistItems()); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('items');?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('wishlist-table')</script>
            <?php else: ?>
                <p class="wishlist-empty"><?php echo $this->__('You have no items in your wishlist.') ?></p>
            <?php endif ?>
            <div class="buttons-set buttons-set2">
                <?php echo $this->getChild('control_buttons')->toHtml();?>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <form id="wishlist-allcart-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/allcart') ?>" method="post">
        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
        <div class="no-display">
            <input type="hidden" name="wishlist_id" id="wishlist_id" value="<?php echo $this->getWishlistInstance()->getId() ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="qty" id="qty" value="" />
        </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var wishlistForm = new Validation($('wishlist-view-form'));
        var wishlistAllCartForm = new Validation($('wishlist-allcart-form'));

        function calculateQty() {
            var itemQtys = new Array();
            $$('#wishlist-view-form .qty').each(
                function (input, index) {
                    var idxStr = input.name;
                    var idx = idxStr.replace( /[^\d.]/g, '' );
                    itemQtys[idx] = input.value;
                }
            );

            $$('#qty')[0].value = JSON.stringify(itemQtys);
        }

        function addAllWItemsToCart() {
            calculateQty();
            wishlistAllCartForm.form.submit();
        }
    //]]>
    </script>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bottom'); ?>
<div class="buttons-set">
    <p class="back-link"><a href="<?php echo $this->escapeUrl($this->getBackUrl()) ?>"><small>&laquo; </small><?php echo $this->__('Back') ?></a></p>
</div>
```

And this is the line 43

```
<?php $this->getChild('items')->setItems($this->getWishlistItems()); ?>
```

Any clue? I'm kinda lost with this error. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Hi Plz check your wishlist.xml with below xml in your theme layout

<wishlist_index_index translate="label">
        <label>Customer My Account My Wishlist</label>
        <!-- Mage_Wishlist -->
        <update handle="customer_account" />
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist" name="customer.wishlist" template="wishlist/view.phtml">
                <action method="setTitle" translate="title">
                    <title>My Wishlist</title>
                </action>
                <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_items" name="customer.wishlist.items" as="items" template="wishlist/item/list.phtml">
                    <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_column_image" name="customer.wishlist.item.image" template="wishlist/item/column/image.phtml" />
                    <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_column_comment" name="customer.wishlist.item.info" template="wishlist/item/column/info.phtml">
                        <action method="setTitle" translate="title">
                            <title>Product Details and Comment</title>
                        </action>
                    </block>
                    <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_column_cart" name="customer.wishlist.item.cart" template="wishlist/item/column/cart.phtml">
                        <action method="setTitle" translate="title">
                            <title>Add to Cart</title>
                        </action>
                        <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_options" name="customer.wishlist.item.options" />
                    </block>
                    <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_column_remove" name="customer.wishlist.item.remove" template="wishlist/item/column/remove.phtml" />
                </block>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="customer.wishlist.buttons" as="control_buttons">
                    <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_button" name="customer.wishlist.button.share" template="wishlist/button/share.phtml" />
                    <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_button" name="customer.wishlist.button.toCart" template="wishlist/button/tocart.phtml" />
                    <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_button" name="customer.wishlist.button.update" template="wishlist/button/update.phtml" />
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>wishlist_customer_sidebar</name></action>
        </reference>
    </wishlist_index_index>
```

Comment: Thank you @faizanbeg! I tried your option but it doesn't work. What I did is to replace the wishlist.xml with the old 1.6.1 file and it works like a charm.

Comment: Yes its xml problem If you find my answer helpfull plz vote